# Coping with lost device in VMR9 custom Allocator-Presenter

Tags: c++, windows, directshow, directx-9

First some necessary pre-amble:

- I'm using DirectX9 and have no choice I'm afraid.  Dealing with legacy code.  Sorry!
- I'm using DirectX9 SDK June 2010.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following.  I have an application which can render in both windowed mode and fullscreen using DirectX.  I need to be able to play video when in fullscreen mode and having a visible transition between rendering of the application and playing video is unacceptable (i.e. kick out of fullscreen and go back in again).  Thus I need to use the same DirectX device to render the application and the video.

I've achieved this by putting together a custom allocator/presenter as per the vmr9allocator example in the DirectX SDK (see e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\vmr9\vmr9allocator).  My version differs somewhat as the DirectX device used by the allocator class isn't owned by that class but is passed in from the rendering part of the application (actually from Angle GL layer to be precise, but this isn't particularly relevant for this discussion).  However the setup of the filter is all the same.

Everything works fine apart from the following scenario.  If the application loses focus then the fullscreen DirectX device is lost.  In this situation I want to stop the video and terminate the device, enter windowed mode and create a new DirectX device for rendering in windowed mode.  I can achieve this, but I seem to leave DirectShow in some unstable state.  The problem manifests itself when I try to subsequently render video in windowed mode.  Rather than using the DX device in this case, I do this by creating a subwindow of my main window for DirectShow to render to.  So in particular for the DX rendering methodology I call

```
SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode_Renderless)
```

and for the windowed version I call

```
SetRenderingMode(VMRMode_Windowless)
```

on the *IVMRFilterConfig* interface.

What I see (after the fullscreen device loss during video) is that the windowed video will not render to my manually specified window.  Instead it insists on opening it's own parentless window exactly as if

```
SetRenderingMode(VMRMode_Windowed)
```

had been called.  If I debug the code then I see that *SetRenderingMode(VMRMode_Windowless)* returns an "unknown error"!

It'll be difficult for me to get advice here on what's wrong with my code as there's a lot of it and posting it all is probably not helpful.  So what I'd like to know is what the correct way to deal with loss of device during video rendering is.  Maybe then I can pinpoint what's going wrong with my code.  With reference to the afore mentioned DX sample, the key problem occurs in the *CAllocator::PresentImage* function:

```
HRESULT CAllocator::PresentImage( 
    /* [in] */ DWORD_PTR dwUserID,
    /* [in] */ VMR9PresentationInfo *lpPresInfo)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CAutoLock Lock(&m_ObjectLock);

    if( NeedToHandleDisplayChange() )
    {}

    hr = PresentHelper( lpPresInfo );

    if( hr == D3DERR_DEVICELOST)
    {
        if (m_D3DDev->TestCooperativeLevel() == D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET) 
        {
            DeleteSurfaces();
            FAIL_RET( CreateDevice() );
            HMONITOR hMonitor = m_D3D->GetAdapterMonitor( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT );
            FAIL_RET( m_lpIVMRSurfAllocNotify->ChangeD3DDevice( m_D3DDev, hMonitor ) );
        }
        hr = S_OK;
    }
    return hr;
}
```

This function is called every frame on a thread which is managed by DirectShow and which is started when the video is played.  The example code indicates that you'd recreate the device here.  Firstly this doesn't make any sense to me as you're only supposed to create/reset/TestCooperativeLevel on the window message thread for DX9, so this breaks that usage rule!  Secondly, I can't actually do this anyway as the DX device is provided extraneously thus we can't reset it.  However I can't find any sensible way to tell the system not to continue rendering.  I can do nothing and return S_OK or some failure code but the problem persists.

So finally, the question! Does anyone know what the correct aproach is to handling this situation, i.e. on device lost just stop video!

N.B. I'm not ruling out some other problem deep in my code somewhere.  But if I at least know what the correct approach to doing what I want is then I can hopefully rule in/out at least one part of the code.

Comment: I also noticed that a IDirect3D9Device is supposed not to be recreated in the VMR9 thread. I use now PostMessage to inform application thread to recreate the device. Not sure if this is a viable option.